# Global variable? Sharing variables across multiple scripts?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a few dozen scripts in the same project for querying different sets of data. I would like the input and output file paths to be the same in all my scripts.

I tried creating a basic method in my assembly:

```cs
namespace FilePaths 
{
    static public class Input 
    {
        static public string GetInputPath() 
        {
            string inputPath = "/some/path/{*}";
            return inputPath;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I try to call it like so:

```sql
USE DATABASE [master];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Assemblies];
@in = FilePaths.Input.GetInputPath();
```

But I can't seem to get it to work... no matter what syntax I try, I get an error. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Path expression has to be a so-called constant-foldable expression. Invoking a class method is not constant-foldable.

If you want to provide a common schema abstraction against a set of files, why don't you look into [table-valued functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt763287.aspx) instead?

Comment: Thanks Mike :) I've worked for Microsoft on more than a few contracts and I can only imagine how busy a PPM is... the fact that you actually take the time to answer questions from the community is AMAZING!!!